# Combo Box Enter Event WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, combobox

I need to have an event fired whenever <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed inside of the combobox. This is a WPF C# 4.0 control, and I am unable to find a specific event handler to do this. I think I am missing something, as this seems like something that would be included. Is there preexisting code to accomplish this task?

I have also tried:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(
    object sender,
    SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Equals(Key.Enter))
     {
         // Do Something
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Return)
        {         
           // do stuff
        }
        else
        {

            // do stuff       
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    private void comboBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
```

or

```
    private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
```

The difference being that KeyUp is when the key is released, KeyDown is when it is first pressed.